# How to you remove unwanted server info on response

Tags: ajax, phpmailer

I have what I think is just a really simple question but I cant seem to find the answer on google or i'm just using the wrong terms.

I'm using PHP Mailer to send emails, there's no problem with that.

My problem is on the response headers I am receiving other information. Some smtp client -> server info. That's fine and all, helps me see status of smtp but now i can't read the ajax response from the page.

Is there a way to remove the client -> server info or a way to just read the returned value of the ajax page?

```
2016-02-27 15:42:06 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP e1sm26974173pas.1 - gsmtp
2016-02-27 15:42:06 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2016-02-27 15:42:07 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [121.54.58.240]
                                      250-SIZE 35882577
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-CHUNKING
                                      250 SMTPUTF8
2016-02-27 15:42:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2016-02-27 15:42:07 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2016-02-27 15:42:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: aUhlbHAuc3d1QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
2016-02-27 15:42:07 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2016-02-27 15:42:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: aWhlbHAxMjM0
2016-02-27 15:42:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Accepted
2016-02-27 15:42:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-02-27 15:42:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 OK e1sm26974173pas.1 - gsmtp
2016-02-27 15:42:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-02-27 15:42:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 OK e1sm26974173pas.1 - gsmtp
2016-02-27 15:42:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2016-02-27 15:42:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354  Go ahead e1sm26974173pas.1 - gsmtp
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Sat, 27 Feb 2016 16:42:06 +0100
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Reset password complete
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <fcad829908390aaf1cf72f28886ac1d5@localhost>
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.13 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:   boundary="b1_fcad829908390aaf1cf72f28886ac1d5"
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_fcad829908390aaf1cf72f28886ac1d5
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_fcad829908390aaf1cf72f28886ac1d5
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_fcad829908390aaf1cf72f28886ac1d5--
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2016-02-27 15:42:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 OK 1456587732 e1sm26974173pas.1 - gsmtp
2016-02-27 15:42:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-02-27 15:42:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection e1sm26974173pas.1 - gsmtp
1
```

I basically just need that "1" at the end as confirmation of ajax call.

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wow, i found my answer as soon as i Posted it here.
Just had to remove

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
```

How silly of me. Thanks anyways!